# Omit response fields on Bing maps query

Tags: bing, bing-maps

I'm looking for ways to reduce my bing maps query response size. For example - If I'm interested in the road distance between Seattle and LA, I'd query:

http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes?wp.0=seattle&wp.1=losangeles&key=
(sorry, you'll have to use your own key)

... and that would give me something this (~1kB):

```
{
...
[
{
estimatedTotal: 1,
resources: 
[
{
__type: "Route:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1",
bbox: 
[
34.053493,
-123.393781,
47.604151,
-118.242588
],
id: "v65,h-1259215200,i0,a0,cen-US,dAAAAAAAAAAA1,y0,s1,m1,o1,t4,w5D47BElTIPU1~ArgmUSjRxBABAADgAVva_j4A0~U2VhdHRsZSwgV0E1~~~,w9ecGAxFDffU1~ArgmUSgxwaIFAADgAQw_AT8A0~TG9zIEFuZ2VsZXMsIENB0~~~,k1",
distanceUnit: "Kilometer",
durationUnit: "Second",
routeLegs: 
[],
travelDistance: 1827.815,
travelDuration: 58573,
travelDurationTraffic: 60478
}
]
}
],
...
```

This would look good, except expanding the routeLegs node gives me another ~23kB of data in the response - the full route - which I don't need. Anyone knows a way how to filter this out (either routeLegs or any of the underlying nodes?)

Thanks

Comment: At the moment there is no option for this. However, this is maybe something that will be added to the service in the future. I'll keep and eye out for this and update this thread if something should become available.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use the routeAttributes parameter documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701717.aspx